# Not Able to Increase the size of heap in JVM greater than 128m

Tags: java

I am using a System having `Windows Server 2003 x86 with 1.66Gb RAM`.

I have an VB application that launches the JAVA VM `i.e loading the jvm.dll`. 
I want to increase the max heap size to be used by my application. I've read various articles & learnt that we use need to use the argument `-Xmx<size>` with the JVM to increase the max heap size. Initially the max heap size was `64 MB`, using the above argument I was able to increase the heap size `upto 128m`. But when i use 256m or greater size the `jvm.dll` is not loaded. Can anyone tell me the solution? The JRe which I'm using is `1.5.0_22`.

Comment: Just it say `invalid heap size ..`?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: there is not any error message shown. it just not loads the jvm.dll

Comment: any reason why you are using the long outdated Java 5 (in case you have a support contract with oracle I would suggest to use this support)

Answer (score 0):

The default size of the heap space in Java is 128MB on most of Sun's 32-bit JVMs, but it varies highly from JVM to JVM.

You can increase size of Java's heap space based on your application's needs. If your application is large and lots of objects are created, you can change size of heap space by using JVM options `-Xms` and `-Xmx`.  `Xms` denotes the starting size of the heap while `-Xmx` denotes maximum size of the heap. There is another parameter called `-Xmn` which denotes the size of new generations of heap space. **The only thing is, you can not change the size of the heap in Java dynamically -- you can only provide Java a heap size parameter while starting the JVM.**

The following three JVM options are used to specify initial and max heap size and thread stack size while running Java programs:

- `-Xms`        set initial Java heap size
- `-Xmx`        set maximum Java heap size
- `-Xss`         set java thread stack size

Comment: I have tried the -Xmx option to increase the heap size but it does not load jvm.dll whean i increase the heap size > 128m

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to run with higher Xmx settings if you use javaw.exe instead of jvm.dll as memory management is different between those two entry points. To try this, find the path to your 32-bit JVM's javaw.exe and specify it via -vm switch